# Alterar cx, cy e raio circle raphael.js

Tags: javascript

Utilisei a biblioteca raphael para criar um certo gráfico. Quero alterar as sua posição e o seu raio. Como posso fazer isso?

Exemplo jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tttxfvcu/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na expressão seguinte X controla a posição do centro e Y o raio do arco:

```
x1 = parseInt(Math.round(X + Y * Math.cos(Math.PI * startAngle / 180)));
```

Os mesmos valores deve ser utilizados nesta expressão:
 <sub><sub>Ex. para x=200 e Y=195</sub></sub>

```
var d = "M200,200  L" + x1 + "," + y1 + "  A195,195 0 " + ((endAngle - startAngle > 180) ? 1 : 0) + ",1 " + x2 + "," + y2 + "
```